# Redirect from facebook to ios app - deep link

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I am not able to redirect to my iOS app from facebook post. When I click on that post its gets open as webpage (somehow dosent identify tags for iOS & dosen't redirect to app). Not sure whether its a ios app OR html content or some other issue.

Myapppp.plist content:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.myapp.xyzxyz</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb123XXX123</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>



AppName: Myapp (As per plist)



<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta property="al:ios:url"                content="myapp://blahblah"/>
     <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id"   content="1234567"/>
     <meta property="al:ios:app_name"       content="Myapp blah blah"/>
</head>
```

When I simply do "`myapp://`" from safari, it takes me to my app and I also tried manually opening "`myapp://blahblah`" which also takes me to app. Hence, I assume my app has valid linking.

When I click on that post from facebook app, it navigates an open that as another webpage which contains one toolbar at the bottom and has one button on it & it shows 3 option. one of them is "open in myapp"

If I try opening some other apps from Facebook app (for e.g. Instagaram post), they too work fine.

Does app name has to be excatly same what I have specified in `info.plist` and the one in `meta_property`? Or is there any other mistake ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @AlizainPrasla Actually later on, we kept it to basic level, where we just used to open the app rather than going to particular screen.

Comment: how you app is redirecting from facebook?

I am having issue. As facebook is using webview. its not redirecting to my app. Any solution?

Comment: Not sure but it was something like 1. Adding URL schemes in your info plist. 2. Adding meta tags in your webpage post. 3. Adding some key in Facebook account. I can't recollect as I am not working on it anymore.

Comment: Thanks anyways. Well in my case. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ help me to check correct meta tags. as i was testing, few metas required more detail of that meta. If you don't provide it. Facebook not going to redirect on your app

Answer (score 2):

## This is expected behavior

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to directly launch a third-party app from within the iOS Facebook app. This is a [known issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1640178609532119/) that Facebook has essentially written off as `wontfix`. This is still possible in the Android Facebook app, but it's unfortunate they haven't been more transparent about the change to the iOS version because there is quite a bit of confusion about it.

Instagram is a special case because it is a Facebook-owned app and gets different treatment.

### But you can work around it

Services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I am on the team) get around this by implementing a judicious combination of App Links, URI schemes, and iOS Universal Links. Essentially what you need to do is open a page in the webview and then have a button or other user-driven CTA event that launches the app from there. It's an extra step for the user, but currently the best workaround. If you just want to be able to post a link that goes into your app when it is installed and otherwise goes to a webpage (or the App/Play Store), then Branch links are definitely your simplest solution.

*Branch link routing logic*

[image: Branch link routing logic]

Comment: Thanks Alex. Will check branch

Answer (score 0):

i think you have not added **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
```

Add this in your plist.

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation
{

    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"Your Url Sceme"])

    {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation];

    }
```

}

\
[image]
hope it will help

Comment: No, its alredy there in plist.

Comment: check Update Answer

Comment: URL Types are added. As per your screenshots, & also contains value for identifier and URL schemes. (As per info.plist content which I had mention in question)

Comment: check Twice it may be possible that you are missing some step. that's only thing done for redirect to facebook and vice versa