# Facebook APP LINK meta tags are not navigating to installed app or appstore in the device

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios10, deep-linking

I have integrated Facebook APP Link meta tags in my HTML page like below.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1146714208755233" />
     <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content=<appstoreid> />
     <meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://eventid/12345" />
     <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content=<App name> />
  </head>
  <body>
     Hello
  </body>
</html>
```

and posted the HTML page link on the **facebook**. Still, the user is not navigating to the app store or my iOS app in the device on tapping the posted link in facebook app in the device. Please help me to find out if I missed anything to implement facebook deep linking.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to share?

Comment: @WizKid, This is the URL 
[link] http://wjerri.mobisoftinfotech.com/event.html

Comment: Look at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=wjerri.mobisoftinfotech.com%2Fevent.html . For some reason you have specified og:url to be imdb so Facebook will fetch tags from there.

Comment: I have updated 'og:url' tags as you suggested, still not working on navigation to app store/native installed app.
wjerri.mobisoftinfotech.com/event.html

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't like users to leave their app. They stopped supporting App Links in their iOS app almost a year ago, but have never publicly acknowledged this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734469/redirect-from-facebook-to-ios-app-deep-link/40745039#40745039) for more.